# Check Box is not visible in gridview

Tags: android

I added some check box to my `gridviewer`. However they are not visible. This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

           <CheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#ffedff38"
            android:backgroundTint="#ff46374b"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:checked ="true"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtn"
            android:onClick="VisualizzaInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff387dff"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info"
            android:alpha="0.7" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code of `gridview`: in this section i add my checkbox to the gridiview; however the checkbox arent visible.

```
    public class CustomGallery extends ActionBarActivity {
        private int count;
        private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
        private String[] arrPath;
        private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<Integer> ordinate = new ArrayList<>();
        private int ID;
        private static int tot;
        private ArrayList<String> imageURLArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        private GridView imagegrid;
        private static boolean[] check = new boolean[]{false};

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            tot = 0;
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                    null, orderBy);
            int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
            this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
            this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            }
            imageURLArray.clear();
            GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            try {
                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        }

        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public ImageAdapter(Context mContext) throws JSONException {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                this.mContext = mContext;
                Collections.sort(SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage(), new DistanceComparator());
                String myString = "http://sistemitelematici.altervista.org/";
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                int id = intent.getIntExtra("userId", -1);
                if(isProfilato(id)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        String s = myString + SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().get(i).getURLWatson();
                        ordinate.add(SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().get(i).getPlaceID());
                        imageURLArray.add(s);
                    }
                    for (int j = 3; j < SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().size(); j++) {
                        String t = myString + SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().get(j).getURL();
                        ordinate.add(SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().get(j).getPlaceID());
                        imageURLArray.add(t);
                    }
                }else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().size(); i++) {
                        String s = myString + SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().get(i).getURL();
                        ordinate.add(SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getAllImage().get(i).getPlaceID());
                        imageURLArray.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return imageURLArray.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                    holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                    //holder.watsonImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.WImage);
                    holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                    holder.btn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }
                else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.checkbox.setId(position);
                holder.imageview.setId(position);
                //holder.watsonImage.setId(position);
                holder.btn.setId(position);

                holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        int id = cb.getId();
                        if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                            cb.setChecked(false);
                            thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                            ID = SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().getImgID().get(id);
                            SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().removeIDMappa(ID);
                            tot--;
                        } else {
                            cb.setChecked(true);
                            thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                            ID = ordinate.get(id);
                            SingletonImageCustomize.getIstance().addIDMappa(ID);
                            tot++;
                        }
                    }
                });
                holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) v;
                        int id = imgBtn.getId();
                        VisualizzaInfo(v,id);
                    }
                });
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageURLArray.get(position)).into(holder.imageview);
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
                holder.id = position;
                position--;
                return convertView;
            }
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageview;
            //ImageView watsonImage;
            CheckBox checkbox;
            ImageButton btn;
            int id;
        }

        public boolean isProfilato(int userID) throws JSONException {
            boolean profilato = false;
            HTTPRequest httpRequest = new HTTPRequest();
            Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(userID));
            httpRequest.execute("estraiProfilo", "http://sistemitelematici.altervista.org/Php/GetProfilato.php", String.valueOf(userID));
            jSonParser js = null;
            JSONArray httpResponse = null;
            try {
                httpResponse = httpRequest.get();
                js = new jSonParser(httpResponse);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Toast.makeText(MyCustomAdapter.this, "La richiesta non � stata portata a termine, per favore riprovare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                //Toast.makeText(MyCustomAdapter.this, "La richiesta non � stata portata a termine, per favore riprovare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                //Toast.makeText(MyCustomAdapter.this, "La richiesta non � stata portata a termine, per favore riprovare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String parser = js.getUserName("profilato");
            if(parser.toString().equals("1"))
                profilato = true;
            return profilato;
        }

        public void VisualizzaItinerario(View view){
            if(tot == 0 )
                Toast.makeText(CustomGallery.this, "Selezionare almeno una destinazione!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(tot <= 8 && tot > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MappaItinerario.class);
                Intent i = getIntent();
                int id = i.getIntExtra("userId", -1);
                intent.putExtra("userId", id);
                imageURLArray.clear();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(CustomGallery.this, "E' possibile inserire al più 8 destinazioni!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    public void VisualizzaInfo(View v,int id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Info.class);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int key = ordinate.get(id);
        int idUser = i.getIntExtra("userId", -1);
        intent.putExtra("userId",idUser);
        intent.putExtra("imageID",key);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't be using "weight" in a relativelayout.

Comment: i delete weight but this solution doesn's fix the problem. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
        holder.checkbox.bringToFront();
```

Try this line after setting the value of imageview in adapter.I think this will not solve the whole problem but atleast your checkbox will be visible. If you have found better answer then post it. It will be helpfull

```
    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/blue"
```

Add these two lines in your checkbox properties in xml hope this helps.